# Jpg content type

Tags: c#, mime-types, content-type

I have the next content-types:

> image/gif
>
> image/png
>
> application/vnd.ms

They all work and recognized the files (gif, png, xls)...

But what is the content-type for jpg? i know that its the type for jpeg:

> image/pjpeg , image/jpeg

But it's not work for jpg.

(I use that with the code:

```
if (contentType == "image/JPEG") ..... 
if (contentType == "image/gif")...
```

For category the files by their extension. maybe there is other way to do that? not by content- type ?)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Caveat: I know almost zero C#.

I suspect this is a casing issue. Try this:

```
if (contentType.ToLower() == "image/jpeg")
```

[RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) indicates that

> The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive. For example, TEXT, Text, and TeXt are all equivalent.

This means that if contentType is coming verbatim from a user-agent, it could have any capitalization, or none at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is case sensitive.
Try:

```
if (contentType == "image/jpeg") .....
```